# Oauth 1: What value should I use for the token secret in HMAC-SHA1 method before having the request token?

Tags: oauth

The HMAC-SHA1 signature method requires a key formed with the concatenation of the client shared secret, '&' and the token shared secret.

I wonder which value should I use for the token shared secret when the client still does not have the request or access token: the client shared-secret again or leave it empty.

From the specification:

> 3.4.2. HMAC-SHA1
>
> The "HMAC-SHA1" signature method uses the HMAC-SHA1 signature
>      algorithm as defined in [RFC2104]:
>
> ```
>  digest = HMAC-SHA1 (key, text)
> ```
>
> The HMAC-SHA1 function variables are used in following way:
>
> text    is set to the value of the signature base string from
>              Section 3.4.1.1.
>
> key     is set to the concatenated values of:
>
> ```
>       1.  The client shared-secret, after being encoded
>           (Section 3.6).
>       2.  An "&" character (ASCII code 38), which MUST be included
>           even when either secret is empty.
>       3.  The token shared-secret, after being encoded
>           (Section 3.6).
> ```
>
> digest  is used to set the value of the "oauth_signature" protocol
>              parameter, after the result octet string is base64-encoded
>              per [RFC2045], Section 6.8.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key should be set to the client shared-secret plus the "&" character when the token shared-secret is unavailable.